# Getting a returned Value from a serial port.(python)

Tags: python, pyserial

I am using Pyserial to write a GUI application to control a Novatech ddsm frequency synthesizer board. I can send a list of different commands via command prompt connected to the serial port (putty) and when I send a correct command it returns 'OK'. I cannot seem to get my python script to see the 'OK' after I write something to the serial port. This is not my actual code since it is quite long but I cannot get this to work either:

```
    import serial
    ser = serial.Serial(
        port='COM3', baudrate=19200, bytesize=8, 
        parity='N',       
        stopbits=1, timeout=1
        )
    command = 'f0 100'
    ser.write(command.encode())
    msg = ser.read(64)
    print(msg)
```

When running this I am only getting back:

```
    b'f0 100'
```

Comment: When using the device manually via putty, do you have to hit Enter at the end of commands?  If so, you need to do the same thing here - put ``\r`` at the end of your command string.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add \r\n in the end, may be it's that! I work with AT Commands and you should add that! \r\n is used with too much commands including AT COMMANDS for gsm modules handling. Also as jasonharper precised, in most terminals you need to hit enter, well it's a standard for the used commands. Mostly to precise where the command end.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to make the call twice, or to use `readline()` several times? If it work you can make a while loop that will run until the return value == `b""` (the line you get when no more response are there). Hope this helps.